# Modifying matrix. Very interesting task for python

Tags: python, arrays, list, matrix

Let's say, we have the following list

> ```
> mag = [
>     [0, 1, 1, 1],
>     [0, 1, 0, 1],
>     [1, 1, 0, 1],
>     [0, 1, 0, 1],
> ]
> ```

**Problem**: need to add or merge new rows like `[1, 0, 0, 1]`.

**Rule**: If I add list which is overlaping with the some of the rows it should be appended or merged depending on which item have been overlapped with the provided item.

**Example** (mag matrix in the beginning):

> ```
> mag.add([0, 0, 1, 0])
> [
>     [0, 1, 1, 1], # << -- here is were overlapped
>     [0, 1, 1, 1], # << -- here will be merged
>     [1, 1, 0, 1],
>     [0, 1, 0, 1],
> ]
> ```

**Example 2** (mag matrix in the beginning):

> ```
> mag.add([0, 1, 0, 0])
> [
>     [0, 1, 1, 1],
>     [0, 1, 0, 1],
>     [1, 1, 0, 1],
>     [0, 1, 0, 1], # << -- overlaps first list from end, will be appended
>     [0, 1, 0, 0],
> ]
> ```

**Example 3** (mag matrix in the beginning):

> ```
> mag.add([1, 0, 0, 0])
> [
>     [0, 1, 1, 1],
>     [0, 1, 0, 1],
>     [1, 1, 0, 1], # << -- overlaps here
>     [1, 1, 0, 1], # << -- here were merged
> ]
> ```

To be more clear, let's say this is tetris where the new list like `[0, 1, 0, 1]` is a figure where `1` is a block and `0` is a free space. We need to understand where the figure might be if it's moving from the bottom to the top.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried to think how it is possible without iterating through all lists.

Comment: I don't understand how you determine which row to merge with, it doesn't look like you're always starting with the same end of the list.

Comment: It's like tetris but starts from the bottom, where 1 is a block and 0 is a free space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here we loop over the matrix from the end, checking at each line if it overlaps.  If it does, we edit the previous line.   If it gets to the top of the matrix, we merge the top line.

```
def overlap(a, b):
    return any(x&y for x, y in zip(a, b))

def merge(a, b):
    return [x|y for x, y in zip(a, b)]

def update_matrix(mat, row):
    if overlap(mat[-1], row): # If the new row doesn't fit at all, add it at the end
        mat.append(row)
        return
    for ind, line in enumerate(reversed(mat)):
        if overlap(line, row):
            change_index = ~(ind-1)  # This trick uses negative indexing to index 
                                     # from the end of the list
            break  # We have the row to merge
    else:
        change_index = 0  # We got to the top, so we need to change the first row
    mat[change_index] = merge(mat[change_index], row)
```

Comment: Wow! It works! Thanks!

Comment: What about using numpy? =)

Comment: My numpy is pretty weak.  One thing I will note is that if you treat these arrays as binary numbers/bit arrays then `overlap` is `a&b != 0` and `merge` is `a|b`.  That seems like the kind of thing numpy might be able to do.

Comment: Yeah, will try to adapt later. Now just need to have a quick solution. Thanks a lot men.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a vectorized solution using numpy. The general idea is to update `mag` by checking several conditions. Firstly `mag` has to be `0`, also its value above has to be `1`, and the update will be applied on the column at which the new row contains a `1`.

The general solution is as follows:

```
def add(x, row):
    import numpy as np
    # Check that the row above contains a 1
    c1 = np.roll(x, 1, axis = 0) == 1
    # Coordinates on where to update with a 1
    ix_x, ix_y = (c1 & (x == 0) & (np.array(row) == 1)[:,None].T).nonzero()
    # If any values satisfy the condition update with a 1
    if ix_x.size > 0:
        mag[ix_x.min(), ix_y] = 1
    else:
        # Otherwise stack the new row at the end
        x = np.vstack([x, row])
    return x
```

---

Lets check now with the 3 proposed examples:

```
# Example 1
row = [0, 0, 1, 0]
add(mag,row)
array([[0, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 1]])

# Example 2
row = [0, 1, 0, 0]
add(mag,row)
array([[0, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 0]])

# Example 3
row = [1, 0, 0, 0]
add(mag,row)
array([[0, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 1]])
```

Comment: Will check it later.